# Saving data to Firebase using Swift

Tags: database, swift, firebase, save

I'm trying to save this information to my Firebase database however I am getting an error "cannot invoke setValue with an argument list of type ([String:String])

```
func addPlaceToFavourites(marker: GMSMarker) {

    let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    var uid: String

    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
        uid = user.uid
    }
    let name = marker.title
    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("favourites").setValue(["lat": lat, "lon": lon, "name": name!])

}
```

I'm trying to add a favourite branch to my userid and then add the variables lat, lon, and name. Given that there can be many favourites for each user should there instead be a favourites branch and then a favouriteid branch and then that is where the lat, lon, and name values should be stored?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: sidenote: you can use `.child("users/\(uid)/favourites")` instead of chained calls

Comment: @mjr I see. Does this create a favourites branch if it doesn't have one already?

Comment: Yes, if you actually set a value for the child. Also, I think your problem is that you're working with a Storage ref, when it should be a Database ref

Comment: You're right! It should be FIRDatabase.database().reference() I just tried that and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @mjr One last thing. Do you know how I can create something like a "favourite.id" to identify whole favourites through individual ids?

Comment: something like [`childByAutoId`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference.html#a18f449729a922397587a9f0c5e0ab812)?